# Error handshake_failure en conexión SSLContext TLS Mutual

Tags: java, rest, ssl, https

Estoy construyendo una aplicación que hace el consumo de un webservice a través de un SSLContext con protocolo TLSv1.2 y TLS Mutual. Como debo de realizar un intercambio de certificados, en ambiente de desarrollo, he creado un certificado autofirmado (SO Windows 8) como se menciona en https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTVVYBcB09Q, que practicamente es crear un certificado, exportarlo e importarlo en los almacenes de confianza para que el certificado quede autofirmado. El envio del mensaje lo realizo como lo indican en https://blog.behrang.org/2019/01/30/ssl-mutual-authentication-java.html, sin embargo estoy recibiendo un mensaje de error desde el server host

`Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

El error que se presenta en el server host es

`error:140890C7:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate
Request processing failed: Connection terminated before request headers read because of the connection error occurs, from URL: 
SSL peer did not send a certificate during the handshake`

Mi certificado fue exportado como un X509 de 64 bit, ese es el mismo que se instalo en el server host y es el mismo que yo importe en un keystore tipo JKS el cual leo y cargo en el SSLContext.

El siguiente es el código fuente del mi aplicación demo

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class SSLDemo {

    public static final String URL = "https://host-destino/context/recurso";
    public static final String PATH_KEYSTORE = "F:\\certificados\\keyStore.jks";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "passwordkeystore";
    public static final String PATH_TRUST_STORE = "F:\\certificados\\trustStore.jks";
    public static final String TRUST_PASS = "passwordtruststore";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(PATH_KEYSTORE, KEY_PASS);
            KeyStore trustStore = getKeyStore(PATH_TRUST_STORE, TRUST_PASS);

            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore)
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, KEY_PASS.toCharArray())
                    .build();

            String[] protocolos = { "TLSv1.2" };
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, protocolos, null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

            // Construye la peticin
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

            System.out.println("Enviando petición: " + httpGet.getRequestLine());

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            try {
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                String result = null;
                if (responseEntity != null) {
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
                }

                EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);
                System.out.println( result);
                httpclient.close();

            } finally {
                response.close();
                httpclient.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    public static KeyStore getKeyStore(String path, String pass) throws KeyStoreException, FileNotFoundException,
            IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        char[] claveKeyStoreArr = pass.toCharArray();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream instreamKey = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        try {
            keyStore.load(instreamKey, claveKeyStoreArr);
            return keyStore;
        } finally {
            instreamKey.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos el código java por favor? Necesitamos más detalles

Comment: De acuerdo a comentario de @PakLeiChong, incluyo código de mi aplicación demo.

Comment: El día de hoy me percate que el metodo `getkeyStore()`, para el almacen `keyStore` (que contiene mi certificado) no esta cargando el certificado que se encuentran dentro del almacen

Answer (score 0):

LLevo tiempo con esta situación para poder conectarme a un servicio RESTFul API con HTTPS, TLSv1.2 y validación de certificados, asi que el problema lo dividí en varias etapas:

1. Conexión sin seguridad.
2. Conexión con certificados del servidor destino (one-way TLS)
3. Conexión con intercambio de certificados (two-way TLS)

**Ambiente**

- java 8 jdk Oracle
- Netbeans 8.2 o 10
- Maven

**1. Conexión sin seguridad**

Este proyecto es creado desde cero por lo cual se iran añadiendo dependencias de acuerdo a como se avance en el mismo.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.26.Final</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Código java

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

public class DemoRestTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSLContext context = null;
        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){ 
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, 
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {} 
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, 
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {} 
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                            return new X509Certificate[0]; 
                    }}}, new SecureRandom());

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DemoRestTest1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;

        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().sslContext(context).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("https://host:port/context/Recursoweb");
        Response response = target.request().get();
        String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(value);
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Algunas notas sobre el código.

Dado que la conexión es sin validación de certificados pero es hacia una `url` con `https` se debe crear un contexto seguro de tipo `SSL`

```
context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

Al iniciar el contexto `context.init()` siempre enviar un arreglo de certificados `TrustManager`, en este caso se envio un arreglo vacio

```
return new X509Certificate[0];
```

Iniciar el contexto con un `SecureRandom()`

Se debe de crear el `target` de forma que ignore la validación del `hostname` para que no lance `excepciones`. Si esto no se hace la conexión es rechazada.

```
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().sslContext(context).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
```

La respuesta puede ser un `Json`, en este caso lo leemos como un `String` y lo imprimimos en consola. Este ejercicio se puede realizar con `RESTeasy Proxy Framework` de esta forma se crean las clases de los objetos a mapear desde el Json, es decir no se recibe un String si que se construye un objeto a partir del `Json`, para este ejercicio puede seguir la guia que se encuentra en https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial, para poder convertir el `Json` en objetos es necesario adicionar la siguiente dependencia

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.26.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Conexión one-way TLS**

Se encuentra en desarrollo...

**Fuentes**

https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl

https://www.baeldung.com/java-ssl-handshake-failures

https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial

https://dzone.com/articles/ssl-based-https-restful-and-soap-client-applicatio

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ia.restapi.doc/topics/r_restapi_sending_https_java.html

https://www.bhaveshthaker.com/24/calling-invoking-secure-restful-web-service-over-https-with-jax-rs-in-java-without-keystore-truststore-information/

https://www.baeldung.com/java-ssl-handshake-failures

https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial

https://www.javaguides.net/2018/10/apache-httpclient-get-post-put-and-delete-methods-example.html